# anaconda dlib and X11

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, dlib

I am on a mac os X Yosemite. I installed dlib with anaconda with:

```
conda install -c menpo dlib=19.4
```

and then removed `X11` from `anaconda/lib` since the `X11` distributed by `anaconda` is presumably broken. Then I installed Xquartz from https://www.xquartz.org/.

But when I go into `ipython` and import `dlib`, and type

```
dlib.image_window()
```

I am still getting error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'image_window'
```

What's the issue?

Note I tried installing `dlib` from scratch when `anaconda` is not in my system, and I ran into all kinds of other issues. So currently I am committed to making dlib work with anaconda, which it does, except for `image_window` and presumably other things associated with `X11`.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue on my Mac. After doing readings on GitHub, I don't think there exists a workaround for installing dlib with anaconda, since something is not right with X11 headers used by anaconda.

I am able to make `dlib.image_window()` work after building dlib from source using the latest version available on the repo. The steps are large the same as suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/ageitgey/629d75c1baac34dfa5ca2a1928a7aeaf) on GitHub. The following steps were carried out in a conda environment I use exclusively for computer vision applications:

1. Clean up dlib installed via conda:
       `conda uninstall dlib`
2. Install cmake and boost-bython with homebrew:
       `brew install cmake`
       `brew install boost-python`
3. Build dlib from source:
   `git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git
   cd dlib/
   mkdir build
   cd build/
   cmake .. -DDLIB_USE_CUDA=0 -DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=1; cmake --build .
   python setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS --no DLIB_USE_CUDA`

The codes took a while to build, but the library works for me in the end.

Comment: I still get the same error. I followed your instructions inside a Docker container (tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3).   The version installed is 19.17.99.
Here is part of my startup script:
`DATE=$( date +%N )
  nvidia-docker run --name tensorflow-gpu-$DATE-0 -it --rm \
  --env="DISPLAY" \
  --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" \
  -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw \ `

Comment: Slight correction to the build command.  After the `cmake` command, but before the `python setup.py...` you need to `cd ..`  Also, I had to remove the `--yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS` part.